# Does USB debugging affect performance during testing

Tags: android, testing

Android website recommends to test an Android application on a real device before releasing it to others. Based on this I would like to know one thing:

When USB debugging is enabled on the device and android applications are tested in real time, does it have any effect on the functionality or performance of the Android phone?

What I mean to say functionality is, about the working speed, app failure or anything similar.

Comment: Nope, the only difference is that Eclipse can sort your Debug logs in a separate window so you can track your application's behaviour in better way. There is no effect on functionality or performance.

Comment: Yes, as long as you do not decide to attach the debugger, the performance is hardly affected in any way. And you shouldn't need a debugger to merely test an app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is none or a little bit that you wont even notice. Your phone will still function normally. You can also use eclipse to log your phones performance and other things. The only thing the eclipse do when you debug the application is attach the debugger to your app and debug it. It will only install your app and lets you test and debug the app. No performance degradation is done. However the application will still occupy the memory on your phone. So it will definitely consume your internal memory like every other application does.

Comment: @Vijararam You can also do a **Vote-Up** by clicking the upper triangle in front of the any one's answer (right above the zero) which really helped you. You can appreciate the help by doing this rather than thanking everyone in the comment (**Actions speak more than words**). And also refer to the [about page](http://stackoverflow.com/about) , you will earn a badge by doing that. And please cosider to do **vote-up** in this question too. **you can vote-up more than one answers for the same question.**

Comment: Vote-up needs minimum 15 reputations, I have only 8, need to wait more.

Answer (score 0):

USB debugging allows you to use the debug in Eclipse or any other Android SDK you are using to test your application. You can have it set to allowed (USB debugging) and you won't even notice it. If anything, it will just drain your battery faster

Comment: Thank you very much for your information, I just forgot to ask about battery usage.

Comment: Battery usage is a little bit more. But if your phone charges when connected to a machine using USB then you won't run out of battery. Instead your phone will charge by USB.

Answer (score 0):

From the perspective of an application it won't affect performance, but at platform level it can.